# How to get multi select with group in ACF?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently working with ACF and I am having a repeater field inside which I am having a text filed. I want to show that text as a dropdown value for users to select from that dropdown instead of using it as a Checkbox/Radio button. Currently I am using it like this[current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO7hc.png)

I want to show this as a dropdown. The code in php I modified like this [php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahygt.png)
but it is showing every option as a seperate dropdown like this [look after modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGolk.png)

Please help me with this how to get this as a dropdown and also how Can I convert it to multi select dropdown with group.

Comment: thats because your entire select element, is inside your loop of rows in the repeater - The select goes on the outside of the loop, og then only the options goes inside the loop.

Comment: basically - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-repeater-data-to-be-used-as-a-select/

Comment: So.. If "have rows", select, while "have rows", option